# Can't call value of non-function type

Tags: ios, swift

Xcode 7, создаю view, получается ошибка на строке:

```
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что есть `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`? Судя по названию, это не функция, а булево поле/свойство.

Comment: да, правильно писать  = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делай так

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```